Why is port number given when doing a DNS lookup?
In ASIO C++ networking library you can resolve an address by creating a query object, whose constructor takes (optionally whether it's ip4 or ip6), a "host" argument and a "service" argument. The "host" is the name of the site you want to resolve to an IP number, and the "service" (I'm guessing) is the port number. So this does a DNS lookup/request, but my understanding is that DNS queries are for looking up associations between names and IP numbers, I don't see how the port figures into this at all.
asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query{"www.google.com", "80"};

Adding further to my befuddlement, there's a "query" constructor that takes just the "service". The comment gives a little explanation:

This constructor is typically used to perform name resolution for
local service binding

I don't understand, I thought DNS lookups were for strictly for (name -> IP number) mappings. If I resolve a name with port 109 and then the same name with port 400, do I get back the same IP numbers?

DNS servers listen to port 53 (by default), and respond on another port (which, by default, is outside the range of ports that standard services listen to).  The components of an IP address are not affected by the numbers of the ports used to communicate with the DNS server, or to read its response.    You might want to dig into the documentation of the ASIO C++ networking library (e.g.  for any class that asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query is derived from) for an explanation of the meaning of a "service" argument.  Port 80 is for http (unencrypted data for web page content) by default

@Peter When you resolve a query with asio, you provide a host and service, (ie., name and port number I'm guessing). The resolver query returns an endpoint that you can use with a socket. Makes sense. It says that if you provide an "" empty string to the "service" argument it resolves the name and puts 0 in the port number of the endpoint. I still don't understand what the port is for. I thought DNS was strictly name -> IPNumber.

The port doesn't do anything for the name lookup; it's just there so the result of a successful lookup is a ready-to-use endpoint that you can connect to because it already has the port number.
Also, the system might have a file like /etc/services, which assigns names to ports. It's likely (although I've never tried it) that the resolver uses this so you could just give https as "service" instead of 443. I think it's too risky to rely on that, though.
The pointless distinction between tcp::resolver and udp::resolver plays into the same area: it allows the resolver to return tcp::endpoint or udp::endpoint (even though they contain exactly the same data...), and also helps with the "services" file lookup.

Thank you. It's more than painful navigating the use of ASIO as the docs are really bad. When will we get proper documentation? Is this the library that'll be adopted into the standard c++ library?

I can't comment on most of this; I'm just a user too :-) Don't even know the original ASIO docs -- I use boost::asio. It takes some time getting used to the docs, but as long as I'm sticking to the high-level stuff it's okay. Besides, I use boost::asio, and "docs" are part of the boost experience... they often document stuff for people that already know everything.

Learning is extremely hard in these circumstances, everything I'm learning seems like some really obscure material for some reason.

"Doesn't do anything" seems to directly contradict the fact that the service is resolved, as well. Regardless, SRV records exist, although Asio doesn't claim to use/support them.

The port number isn't given. What is given is a service name. If it is numerical, it will be returned as the port, otherwise it will be resolved, just like the host.
The same goes for the host, by the way (if it contains an IP address, it will be returned as-is). If you are in a security sensitive setting you can always consider passing the relevant flag to indicate that host and/or service must be valid without further resolution: see e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__resolver_query_base/numeric_service.html
The distinction between protocol families exists so it's easier to write protocol-generic code. The difference will be mainly that the produced endpoints know the correct protocol family to use.
